# Merging two lazy lists in Scala

Tags: scala, list, merge, functional-programming

Can anyone help me ?
I need to create function «lazymerge» which generates a new sorted list from two sorted lazy lists. You need to use streams. 
Example: [1;3;5;7;9;11] and [2;4;6;8] gives you [1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;11]

I tried everything :(
Also, it must be done in functional style.

Comment: Please show what you tried so far.

Comment: Doesn't working.

Comment: Even it's not working, you should share what you've done so far. This is how we can figure out what it's not working. This is how SO works. Please read this : [How do I ask a good question ?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: val sorted = (listFirst++listSecond).sorted

Comment: But I don't know how to make it with LAZY lists

Comment: `I tried everything`. What are those things? What is your `lazy list` ? Do you mean http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/collection/immutable/Stream.html ?

Comment: "You need to use streams" change of person is a dead giveaway that this is an assignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to compare the current heads of both streams and use the smaller one as the current head of final stream for each iteration.

```
val intStream1 = 1 #:: 5 #:: Stream(10)

val intStream2 = 2 #:: 4 #:: Stream(12)

def sortedMerge(stream1: Stream[Int], stream2: Stream[Int]): Stream[Int] = (stream1.isEmpty, stream2.isEmpty) match {
  case (false, false) => (stream1.head <= stream2.head) match {
    case true => stream1.head #:: sortedMerge(stream1.tail, stream2)
    case false => stream2.head #:: sortedMerge(stream1, stream2.tail)
  }
  case (false, true) => stream1
  case (true, false) => stream2
  case (true, true) => Stream.empty[Int]
}
}

val sortedStream = sortedMerge(intStream1, intStream2)
```

Comment: @WillNess I too wish for down-voters to raise their concerns in comments. It is a mystery as of now.

Comment: maybe it was because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47455736/merging-two-lazy-lists-in-scala/47457017?noredirect=1#comment81880498_47455736) reason. btw "orderedMerge" could have been a better choice. (you also forgot to rename the recursive call).

Comment: Yes may be. But Streams in Scala can be confusing to beginners.